# How to remove dependency of msnodesqlV8 from sequelize while creating mssql connection

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying to configure connection to mssql using sequelize. Is there any way I can remove dependency on msnodesqlv8?

Below is the snippet I am using to create sequelize object

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
   logging:log,
   dialect: 'mssql',
   dialectModulePath: 'msnodesqlv8/lib/sequelize',
   dialextOptions: {
     connectionString:process.env.connectionString,
     encrypt: false
  },
   operatorAliases:false
})

sequelize.authenticate()
   .then(fuction(res){console.log("Connected successfully")
   .catch(function(error){console.log("Connection Error:", error)
```

The goal is to migrate the backend to linux. And due to dependency on msnodesqlv8 I am not able to migrate backend to linux from windows. Please do let me know if I am not clear at any part.

Comment: msnodesqlv8 *is* supported on Linux... [1](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/issues/51#issuecomment-683900664), [2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8)

Comment: Looking at this I might need to upgrade msnodesqlv8 and odbc driver. Right now I am using msnodesqlv8-2.0.8 and odbc driver 11. And document say msnodesqlv8-2.4.7 and odbc driver 17 needs to be used.

Comment: If you're using 2.0.8 the. Linux is supported. That was added in version [2.0.0](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/releases/tag/v2.0.0). Though that doesn't mean you shouldn't be updating your package.

Comment: Ohhh... Now I see... The problem is in ODBC driver. I will initially try just by updating ODBC 11 -> ODBC 17. I hope that should work fine.